# Terraform: Creating multiple instances with Terraform with for_each and mapping security_group_rule

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I have a scenario where I need to create multiple EC2 instances which are part of a cluster.These hosts have to be accessible on specific ports from one another and need to have two ebs_volumes attached to them of size 16GB and 700GB.
snip of my variable.tf looks like this:-

```
variable "instances" {
  default = {
            instance_name = "a"
            tcp_ports = ["53","22","2022","80","443"]
            udp_ports = ["53","67","68","123","161","162","500"]
            "xvdf" = "16"
            "xvdg" = "700"
            }
}
```

I am struggling to get this mapping to work with my TF script:-

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "tcp_ingress" {
  for_each = {
    for inst in local.instances : inst.tcp_ports => {
      for i in inst: i.tcp_ports => i
  }
  }
  type = "ingress"
  from_port = each.value.tcp_ports
  to_port   = each.value.tcp_ports
  protocol = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks = [ for i in aws_instance.instance: format("%s/32", i.private_ip ) ]
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.ha-sg.id
}
```

Is there a way I can iterate through  the ports and form the security group rules.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are actually using? In your for_each you have  `local.instances` which would be a list, but your provided `variable "instances"` which is not a list, but a map.

Comment: should be like this.
```for_each = {
    for inst in var.instances : inst.tcp_ports => {
      for i in inst: i.tcp_ports => i
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way I can iterate through the ports and form the security group rules.

Since your `variable "instances"` is **a single map**, to access the `tcp_ports` you can simply do the following:

```
var.instances.tcp_ports
```

Then to use it in `for_each`:

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "tcp_ingress" {

  for_each    = toset(var.instances.tcp_ports)

  type        = "ingress"
  from_port   = each.value
  to_port     = each.value
  protocol    = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks = [ for i in aws_instance.instance: format("%s/32", i.private_ip ) ]
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.ha-sg.id
}
```